# Serial port - no bytes available

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I'm developing an app that takes bytes from COM port and manage them.
Unfortunately I don't have the opportunity to work on pc where this app will run, so I need a way to send "fake data" on my COM port so my app can read it.

Whatever I do, no bytes are available on selected COM port.
This is a basic sample:

```
'First I create and open desired COM port
Dim port = New SerialPort(cboPorts.SelectedItem, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
port.Open()
If Not port.IsOpen Then Exit Sub
```

Then, with a timer, I try to write on it and then read:

```
Private Sub tmrTest_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrTest.Tick
    Dim tot = rnd.Next(0, 3)
    If tot > 0 Then
        Dim buffer(tot) As Byte
        rnd.NextBytes(buffer)
        port.Write(buffer, 0, tot)

        Dim t = port.BytesToRead
        Console.WriteLine("Got {0} bytes on COM port", t)
    End If
End Sub
```

In real app, bytes are not read right after they are written (I have a timer that reads COM port every second) but result is the same: `port.BytesToRead` is always zero.

Comment: There are several Ethernet2RS232 adapters out there. I use them for such things. So you can send data from the onboard serial port and receive it via the adapter or the other way.

Comment: Calling DiscardOutBuffer() right after you call Write() ensures that *nothing* is being sent.  Delete that.  BytesToRead will always be zero, it takes time for the bytes to be written and for the device to respond.

Comment: Sorry @HansPassant, that was an attempt I changed later. Edited my question but still data is not read even after 10 seconds! Consider this is just a sample: real app reads serial port every second and nothing is fiund, never!!

Comment: That's a very common problem, forgetting to turn on the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties is the usual cause.

Comment: @HansPassant: sorry Hans, that didin't solve my problem; finally I decided to test the app in a different way: `#if DEBUG generate random numbers #else read COM port #endif`... that's the best I could do, waiting to run trhe app on target pc :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serial ports don't work this way. You can't read back the data you just wrote out. When you read, you you read the *input* buffer and when you write you write to the *output* buffer (you can't *read* the *output* buffer)

The only way to simulate what you want is to use another machine and connect a serial port between them, or read and write to two different serial ports on the same machine AppA writes to serial port 1 and reads from port 2 and AppB does the opposite.

Comment: Didn't know :( Thank you for your answer!